# Publish with Facebook PHP api => UOAuthException: (#282) Requires extended permission: share_item thrown

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Here is My code :

```
<?
session_start();

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/fonctions.php');

include '../api/facebook.php';
include '../api/xhttp.php';


  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = '35455XXXXXXX207';
  $config['secret'] = '6006855f3aXXXXXXXXX9bce45a426';
  $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);


$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Hello from my App!',
    'link'      => 'http://www.masteringapi.com/',
    'caption'   => 'Visit MasteringAPI.com For Facebook API Tutorials!',
    'access_token'  => $access_token
);

$retour_login = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['session']), true);
$uid = $retour_login['uid'];
$access_token = $retour_login['access_token'];

$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);

?>
```

But it returns :  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
Any ideas ?

Thanks!

---

Here is My new code :

```
<?


  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = '3545XXXXXXX6207';
  $config['secret'] = '60068XXXXXXXXXXXe45a426';


  $facebook = new Facebook($config);


$retour_login = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['session']), true);
$uid = $retour_login['uid'];
$access_token = $retour_login['access_token'];


$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

if(!isset($_GET['session'])) {
    $params = array(
    'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    'display' => 'popup', 
    'req_perms' => 'email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location',
    'ext_perms' => 'publish_stream,share_item,manage_pages'
    );
    header("Location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
}



        $args = array(
                'message'   => "XXXX",
                'link'      => 'XXXX',
                'name'      => 'XXXX',
                'picture'   => 'XXXX',
                "caption"=> "lien.com",
                      "type"=> "link");

        $post_id = $facebook->api("/me/links", "post", $args);

?>
```

This time i get this error : OAuthException: (#282) Requires extended permission: share_item thrown

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: your args does not have access_token, use $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); to get the access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing it the access token.

Check out getAccessToken().

Comment: Thanks, but i dont figure how to use this, any ways ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample it looks like you are trying to use the variable $access_token to create your $args array, before you define the $access_token variable. I would switch the order of variable definitions:

```
$retour_login = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['session']), true);
$uid = $retour_login['uid'];
$access_token = $retour_login['access_token'];

$args = array(
'message'   => 'Hello from my App!',
'link'      => 'http://www.masteringapi.com/',
'caption'   => 'Visit MasteringAPI.com For Facebook API Tutorials!',
'access_token'  => $access_token
);
```

This is assuming $retour_login['access_token'] contains a valid Facebook access token. Otherwise you will need to fetch the current user's access token using the Facebook SDK:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Hi i dont get the same error now, i upgraded my code This time i get this error : OAuthException: (#282) Requires extended permission: share_item thrown

Any ideas ?

Comment: A couple of suggestions with your new code:
- You're redirecting to Facebook's dialog, so I would request the "page" type display
- The permissions you request are part of the "scope" parameter, not separated into "ext_perms" and "req_perms"
- The share_item permission should be a part of publish_stream, so you shouldn't need to request it

`$params = array(`
`'locale' => 'fr_FR',`
`'display' => 'page',`
`'scope' => 'email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location,publish_stream,manage_pages'`
`);`